# How to search in git commit comments?

Tags: windows, git, command-line

I am using git and trying to find information about featurebranches in the master branch. How can I search for a string inside the git commit comments?

Answer (score 1):

git git log --grep:

```
git log --all -i -E --grep="some.?regexp.?pattern"
```

Comment: do you have sample of that? fe the word unit is in the comments but does not display:  git log --all -i -E -n --grep=^unit

Comment: unless you are "absolutely sure" the word unit is at the beginning of a line (the **^** points in that direction), then just use ```--grep=unit```.

Comment: By the way, removed the -n from the options on the answer. That works to show line numbers of files when using git grep, which is not correct in this case.

Comment: I tried this on my git's repo and it works like a charm: ```git log -E -i --grep="BISECT"```